# How to use UILabel to show the HTML string that contains the background-color and the border-radius？

Tags: html, ios, css, uilabel

```
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"<div style='background-color:#34c083;line-height:20px;width:65px;border-radius:5px;color:#fff;margin-top:5px;;padding-top:2px;height:20px;'><a href='https://www.baidu.com' style='text-decoration:none;color:#fff;'>hello!!!</a></div>"];       
NSError* error = nil;

NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:&error];

UILabel *textView = [UILabel new];
textView.attributedText = text;
```

the result is not the same as I expected. why？ how to fix？ thanks.

Comment: what you want in uilabel ?

Comment: I need show background-color and CornerRedius in UILabel by HTML String，instead of changing the property of UILable.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
NSString *html = @"<div style='background-color:#34c083;line-height:20px;width:65px;border-radius:5px;color:#fff;margin-top:5px;;padding-top:2px;height:20px;'><a href='https://www.baidu.com' style='text-decoration:none;color:#fff;'>hello!!!</a></div>";
NSError* error = nil;

NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:&error];

UILabel *textView = [UILabel new];
textView.attributedText = text;
[textView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
[textView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: thanks,i dont want to changing the property of UILable. only use HTML string sented by the server.